# Which is correct? "I like Ford Explorers" vs. "I like Ford Explorer" vs. "I like the Ford Explorer"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, articles, definite-articles

Suppose you are talking about cars, and are asked what car manufacturer's vehicle you like, which sentence is correct or sounds more natural?

1. > I like **Ford Explorers**, because **they are** well-equipped.

   (the plural form of a proper noun)
2. > I like Ford **Explorer**, because **they are** well-equipped.

   (a proper noun w/o any articles)
3. > I like **the Ford Explorer**, because **it is** well-equipped.

   (a proper noun with a definite article)

Here, I'm talking about cars in general, and not about some specific cars in front of me.

I know I must use a plural noun after the verb "like" in a sentence as "I like poodles." for example. But I'm not sure whether I could say just as the same when it comes to a specific model name of industrial products like cars or smartphones.

I'd very much appreciate it if you could help me with this question.

Comment: See http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html

Comment: Thank you for a very useful information, Clare.
It's quite interesting for me to read the difference between the three types of generic nouns.
Now I understand it is the construction that really means, not the articles; but how about generic nouns coming to the object position?
As I wrote in my reply to Lars, I found lots of examples of "I like the-products model-" sentences, which confuse me very much.
I'd be very much grateful if you tell me your opinion.
Thank you.

Comment: The generic noun phrases can be in either subject or object position. So you can say *I like the leopard.  It's my favorite animal.* Here  *the leopard* is a generic noun phrase. Same with *I like the Ford Explorer*.

Comment: Thank you again, Clare. Your comments help me organize the concept of articles in my mind.
It was a bit of surprise that I can say "I like the leopard," meaning just the same as "I like leopards" in some context. What I learned at school was that I had to use plural nouns in the object position and avoid using a noun with a generic definite article there. But now I understand it's possible. 
Here is another question. Is there any difference between the two sentences? 
Which do you think is more natural to say?

Comment: The difference between *I like the leopard* (generic noun phrase) and *I like leopards* (generic noun phrase) is explained in the article I first linked you to: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html It's somewhat technical. Buy it's all explained there.

Comment: Thanks again, Clare. I'm not sure if I get it right, but I think I am trying to understand what's written in the link you showed me somehow. Thanks to the comments from you and Lars, I guess I am understanding articles, which is still difficult and needs some more time for me to process the information. But I'm going for it.

Well, I just wanted to ask you which is your first choice if one of your friends asks you what your favorite car is. I know it depends on situations, but in everyday conversation, how would you say? I could not be more grateful if you could tell me about this.

Comment: I would say *My favorite car is the Ford Mustang*. And again, *the Ford Mustang* is a "generic noun phrase," and specifically, "a definite generic noun phrase," which (as the article mentions) is talking about the "prototypical Ford Mustang". But don't worry too much about the word or even concept of prototypical. Most native speakers do not understand generic noun phrases, or the nuances in meanings between the three types of them as explained in the article.

Comment: So in the above sentence, *the Ford Mustang* is a generic noun phrase. It is not referring to any Ford Mustang that I can go to an auto store and sit in or actually see or drive. It's talking about the prototypical Ford Mustang, which exists as an ("imaginary") prototype.

Comment: But, if there are five real, actual cars in front of me, five different kinds, one of which is a Ford Mustang (the others are a Mazda a Honda, a Chevy, and a Dodge). And my friends asked me *Which of these five cars is your favorite?* And I point to the Ford Mustang and say *(Out of these five cars) I like the Ford Mustang*, ***then*** this noun phrase *the Ford Mustang* is *not* a generic noun phrase, because I'm talking about one actual Ford Mustang that actually exists and I can go sit in it and drive it.

Comment: Note in my above comments the two sentence openings  *My favorite car is...* and *I like...* are equivalent and interchangeable, in this context.

Comment: Your comments always make sense and I really appreciate them, Clare.
Yes, that seems to be the exact point I wanted to confirm. You paraphrased the sentence "I like the Ford Mustang" as "My favorite car is the Ford Mustang," not as "My favorite CARS are Ford MustangS," which gave me some hint to think over generic definite article and generic plural. Like you have been explaining, when talking about one's preferred vehicles, we have some prototypical imaginary car in mind, and that's why we use generic definite article, not generic plural here.  Did I get it right?

Comment: You asked me how *I* would answer the  question. I gave you two possible sentences with the definite generic noun phrase. However, someone could say, in response to your question, *I like Ford Mustangs*. This is the plural generic noun phrase. We are no longer dealing with the 'prototypical' Ford Mustang. To quote  @Lawler's paper we're dealing with "the Norm of a species over its individuals, as perceived, of course, by the speaker." It "implies a generalization based on experience of several individuals."

Comment: IOW, *different* Ford Mustangs exist. Even in the same model year there are different engines available, different options packages, etc. But as I think about   them, I can say *I like Ford Mustangs* or,  probably  less likely but still valid, *Ford Mustangs are my favorite (cars)*.  Probably  not every single one (just as Lawler's paper says not all tigers are big with regard to *Tigers are big*), but based on the Mustangs I've experienced, *I like Ford Mustangs (in general)* and *Ford Mustangs are my favorite* are valid  possible responses.

Comment: See [this example](https://books.google.com/books?id=-tEXBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&dq="are+my+favorite"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLmN6Jr_fWAhXHTCYKHaatDZA4ChDoAQhMMAg#v=onepage&q=%22are%20my%20favorite%22&f=false). *Twenties are my favorite guns.* The word *twenties* is short for '20-guage shotguns', so you have *20-guage shotguns are my favorite guns*.  This is using the plural generic noun phrase to answer the question, what is your favorite guage shotgun?

Comment: I can't tell you how much I appreciate your kind and sincere comments, Clare.  Learning something that doesn't exist in my own mother tongue is really fun. Thank you for being patient enough and offering me your profound knowledge. BTW, are you a linguistics teacher or something? I guess it's very difficult to explain one's mother tongue to a foreigner like me. Being able to speak a language is quite different from being able to explain it logically. I'm just curious about your background.

Comment: Thanks for the new link.
Well, I suppose I have to read or listen more to grab the exact image of articles. That's what I think I need now. So I read the link you showed me with much interest.

As you told me, the author uses generic plural for the 20 gauge. 
But very interestingly, except the 20 gauge, the author uses the generic articles for all other gauges as in 28, 16, and 12 each. And even for the 20, his conclusion is expressed by using the generic article.
Ummm, I feel like I've gotten lost in a maze again....haha.

Comment: Anyway, in conclusion, both can be said;  I like Ford Mustangs and I like the Ford Mustang, even though there are some difference in the attitude the speaker has towards the object itself.
If I have more experiences with something personally, I may well choose generic plural, because I know lots of the same kind, and can generate in mind a norm of them. But in general speaking, it is more likely to use the generic article, having the prototype of the object in mind. This is my understanding so far. Am I right?

Comment: That  book is  a bit humorous. Because it means that the author considers *every* guage shotgun as his favorite. :)  it's like saying, the Ford Mustang is my favorite car and the Chevy Malibu is also my favorite car. A little nonsensical. But hunters tend to love all their guns. Nothing wrong with that. They each have their own purpose. He has written that way deliberately to make a point and be a little humorous at the same time. You can reach me at clareeverywhere at gmail dot 
 com if you wish to email me.

Comment: Yes, I felt the author's passion towards shotguns. As for me, I'd be like this when I go to Baskin-Robins. I can't decide my favorite, the best one. I love all the flavor. :-p 

Thank you Clare for helping me understand the generic article and plural this time. Your comments and all the links gave me the opportunity to think over the subject and strengthen the knowledge. 
I owe you big time!

Answer (score 2):

Sentences 1 and 3 are correct, sentence 2 is not possible.

When talking about things in general, we usually use a plural or uncountable noun with no article. We would not usually say 'I like the poodle'- it is potentially confusing as this usage would usually mean something that is known / identified.

We often use 'the' + singular noun if the item we are talking about is, for example, an invention or a musical instrument.

It is also possible to generalise using 'a' / 'an' with a singular countable noun. Example: An elephant needs lots of food.

Michael Swan's 'Practical English Usage' has more details and examples.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Lars. 
I totally agree that when I mention general nouns like dogs or cats, I have to use the plural forms to make a sentence "I like cats" and cannot say "I like the cat." 
But how about products' names such as Toyota Carolla, Samsung Galaxy, or Asus Nexus7? 
I am asking this question because I found more examples of "I like the Ford Explorer" than "I like Ford Explorers" on the Internet. 
This result comfused me because my understanding about the articles was just what you told me.
 It would be a great help if you could share your opinions about this.

Comment: Not an easy area to clarify because the rules are partly grammar based, partly about usage. A distinguished linguist once told me that our rules are surprisingly practical in that they are based on how we actually perceive or see things. When thinking about cats and Ford Explorers (for example), this seems to work. We don't usually visualize a particular cat when speaking of cats in general (hence, the plural seems natural). With certain objects, though, we do tend to visualize the object, often because we imagine ourselves owning it. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Having said that, there is nothing wrong with 'I like Ford Explorers' nor with 'The giraffe is the tallest animal in the world' (a little more formal, might be heard in a documentary) but you would have to be careful about the context in which you used the latter in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you again for your comments, which help me sort out my thought on articles.
Having read all the comments I received so far, I guess the reason why people use a definite article in the "I like 'the product name'" sentence is because they are talking about the prototype of the product they are mentioning and want to emphasize that what they like is THE Ford Explorer, not THE Toyota Corolla.
(The definite article has the meaning of emphasizing distinction from other kinds in the same category, right?)

Comment: Before asking this question here, I wasn't fully sure whether I could say like that. But I've become more confident with the usage of articles thanks to your detailed and understandable comments.
We Japanese have no articles in our language so that they are very difficult for us to use correctly. But learning such things is really fun, because through doing this, we can also see cultural difference behind languages. 
Thanks anyway for your kind help.
I really really appreciate it!!